# Removing one of two duplicate-key ASPXAUTH cookies. Code works, but why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

My question is about how to remove an ASPXAUTH cookie from a specific domain when I have two ASPXAUTH cookies active for the site.

**The setup:**

I have two sites: usermanagement.domain.com and shop.domain.com

On the user "usermanagement" site, administrators can impersonate users who exist on the "shop".

When logging in "usermanagement", an ASPXAUTH cookie is created for the usermanagement.domain.com site.
When impersonating a user, another ASPXAUTH cookie is created for the .domain.com domain. (Which practically authenticates the user on shop.domain.com as well. It works this way because usermanagement.domain.com cannot create a cookie for shop.domain.com - therefore, the shared .domain.com is used instead.)

This means that when an administrator impersonates a user, the following two ASPXAUTH cookies exist:

- .ASPXAUTH    (Domain: usermanagement.domain.com)
- .ASPXAUTH    (Domain: domain.com)

Now, when an administrator stops impersonating a user, I want to remove the ".domain.com" ASPXAUTH cookie. The following code accomplishes my goal:

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(".ASPXAUTH"))
{
    var domain = _configurationService.GetB2BSettings().BackOfficeAndImpersonationDomain;
    var impersonationCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH")
    {
        Domain = domain,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    };
    Response.Cookies.Add(impersonationCookie);
}

return Redirect(homeUrl);
```

And this is where I have a sort "it works, but I don't know why"-moment. The above code removes the .ASPXAUTH with ".domain.com" domain. The other ASPXAUTH cookie gets to live.

**My question is:** How does this work?

The new cookie created in the above excerpt is not merged into the request cookies at this point. In fact, just before the Redirect is performed, the request contains 3 .ASPXAUTH cookies (two original ASPXAUTH cookies, and the newly added cookie).

(On a side note: I know this setup is not necessarily ideal or intuitive, but due to the scope of the task, I'm not going to change the domain/site setup at the moment. I'm mostly curious about how the above code works.)